# Is it possible to create reusable Nintex function, workflow and forms template

Tags: nintex

Is it possible to create reusable function, workflow and forms template?

Currently we are working on Lotus notes migration project to Nintex and there are a lot of functions,forms and workflows that are similar to each other.

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there certainly is. The following links should set you on the right path:-

[User Defined Actions.](https://community.nintex.com/community/build-your-own/blog/2014/05/12/best-practice-for-workflow-design-user-defined-actions)

[Reusable Workflows.](https://support.nintex.com/SharePoint/Workflow/2013/Reusable_Workflow_Template_Versus_Site_Collection_Reusable_Template)

[Form Templates](https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1046)